# Como usar clases en DLL

Tags: python, c++, c, go, dll

Estoy en un proyecto y pues está hecho en python pero hay cosas que son más fáciles con una clase hecha en C/C++ o Golang y por ejemplo si tenemos una dll con funciones podemos usarlas en python pero como usar una función que nos que nos retorne una clase ? O que pida una clase como argumento

Comment: Si está hecho en C/C++ o Golang dudo que vaya a pedir o retornar una clase Python.

Comment: Tengo entendido que es posible usar clases de C++ en un DLL, y que solo va a funcionar con el mismo compilador ya que cada compilador tiene su propio name mangling.

Comment: Es totalmente posible crear binding a clases de C++, una prueba obvia de ello son los binding a Qt para Python  PySide y PyQt (que usan [Shiboken](https://www.qt.io/blog/2018/05/31/write-python-bindings) y SIP respectivamente para el proceso de wrapping). Hay mas herramientas para facilitar el proceso de binding, como [Pybin11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html). Y siempre queda la opción más dura, la manual via C-API/ctypes usando C de intermediario.

Comment: En cuanto a Go, ni idea, mi experiencia con los binding es mayoritariamente con C y Rust (y anecdóticamente algo de C++), pero dado que C suele actuar como nexo común...

Comment: Pero como se haría en python el utilizar los objetos, normal como cualquier otro ??